# Unable to split spring XD stream delimited by "

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to analyze log stream and want to split the log statement by, When I create stream below, I am getting following error.

Attempt 1:

```
xd:>stream create words --definition "http --port=9000 | splitter --expression=payload.split('\"')  | log"
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could not find module with name 'splitter' and type 'sink'
```

Attempt:2

```
xd:>stream create words --definition "http --port=9000 | splitter --expression=payload.split('"')  | log"
stream create words --definition "http --port=9000 | splitter --expression=payload.split('"') | log"
                                                                                                ^
```

Cannot have an unbalanced number of quotation marks

Can I achieve this only by creating customer processor?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

> xd:>stream create words --definition "http --port=9000 | splitter --expression=payload.split('\u0022')  | log" --deploy
>   Created and deployed new stream 'words'

Note the usage of unicode for double quotes.

> xd:>http post --data "http \" log"

Comment: Getting error below, when I try the same stream definition. Something to do with Spring XD version? I am using 1.1.0 release.

xd:>stream create words --definition "http --port=9000 | splitter --expression=payload.split('\u0022') | log" --deploy
Command failed org.springframework.xd.rest.client.impl.SpringXDException: Could not find module with name 'splitter' and type 'sink'

Comment: ok, Looks like you need to do this in 1.1.x release: stream create words --definition "http --port=9000 | splitter --expression=payload.split('\\u0022') | log" --deploy. Note the `\\\` before unicode.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
module compose my_splitter --definition 'splitter --expression=payload.split(\'"\')'
stream create words --definition "tcp --port=9000 --decoder=RAW --outputType=text/plain | my_splitter | log" --deploy
```

then I am testing this using

```
echo 'foo"faa' | netcat 192.168.59.3 9000
```

I replaced the http source by a tcp source, such that I can test with netcat. But this should also work with http.

Output on the xd-singlenode log:

```
2015-05-21 22:27:22,463 1.1.0.RELEASE  INFO pool-11-thread-2 sink.words - foo
2015-05-21 22:27:22,464 1.1.0.RELEASE  INFO pool-11-thread-2 sink.words - faa
```

Hope this helps